# htaccess stuck in loop

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have fairly basic knowledge when it comes to htaccess. I have a Website that is dynamic, so when a sub folder for example /services/right-to-manage exists it ignores the /services/ and grabs the right-to-manage and uses this to find the page from the database. The line of code in the htaccess for this is:

```
RewriteRule ^services/(.*)$ /$1
```

This works fine, until I add a 301 redirect below:

```
Redirect 301 /right-to-manage /services/right-to-manage
```

It then gets stuck in a loop and the browser stops the page continuing.

Any info / help greatly appreciated.

Comment: But why do you need that 301 rule?

Comment: SEO company insisting it must be there

Comment: But that's not enough information to get help on SO